# Possible distinct positive real $x,y,z \neq 1$ with $x^{(y^z)} = y^{(z^x)} = z^{(x^y)}$ in cyclic permutation?

Tags: inequality, recreational-mathematics

Can we have distinct positive real  $x,y,z \neq 1$ with
$$  x^{\left( y^z \right)}  =   y^{\left( z^x \right)}  =  z^{\left( x^y \right)}      $$ in cyclic permutation?

It does not work well if any variable is 1. Also, it obviously works if all three are equal. I think if two are equal, probably the third must match as well. If there is anything else, one would expect a curve of some sort..I guess from what I am asking, one might as well demand $x < y < z.$ NO, not the same as $x < z < y$ as not cyclically equivalent, so maybe drop that.

Suggested by [what is the largest number here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493554/what-is-the-largest-number-here)

Comment: Nice descriptive title.

Comment: @GitGud, thanks. I tried it with integers and got nothing, so I thought positive reals...

Comment: I laughed in real life.

Comment: @GitGud, good. I do try to add a little humor...also it is quite true

Comment: I think, mucinex is an answer.

Comment: @studiosus, just saw my allergy/asthma doctor, the answer turned out to be amoxicillin. Biggest pills I have ever seen, and the first time in my life i had trouble swallowing a single pill. So, it began with a cold, then something else showed up.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Gulp!

Comment: Perhaps it is because i have been coughing and my throat hurts a bit already...My fish oil pills are actually larger, and i take six of those at once. But they are smooth on the outside.

Comment: Looks like a kind of last fermat jagy theorem showing up^^

Comment: I don't find anything stupid in having bad cold with cough.

Comment: "So, it began with a cold, then something else showed up." "...the answer turned out to be amoxicillin."  Something like this happened to me last month -- and the amoxicillin may have contributed to the DVT I ended up with after a transatlantic flight a few days later. Take care!

Comment: @BobPego, thanks. I'm not travelling this month. On the other point, doctors have gotten a bit gunshy about antibiotics, they fear creating resistant strains. So, I get something similar about once a year, most years I muddle by with over the counter pills.

Comment: @WillJagy Gulping Amoxycillins are a real pain. I was given a 7-days course a few days ago and one of them almost gagged me. So afterwards I split them in half and eat them one at a time. Nice question, by the way!

Comment: Has anyone checked numerically whether there is a solution?

Comment: @barto, I later posted it at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/143848/simultaneous-zero-set-of-two-equations-in-mathbb-r3 where there is a pretty convincing animation by Robert Israel. There was also an answer by fedja, one of the best problem solvers on either site and my bet to be able to do this, but he became unconvinced ( I'm guessing) and deleted it about six minutes later; this was on winter break, December 29, 2014. Also possible that he knew it was correct and deleted it anyway, but more likely he realized some less than obvious gap in it.

Comment: I feel like I should note the original title for posterity: "This is stupid but I have a bad cold with cough"

Answer (score 3):

I think I've solved it, but I just don't trust myelf.  So please hop on and correct me if I've done something stupid..

By way of contradiction, let's assume the equality $x^{(y^z)}=y^{(z^x)}=z^{(x^y)}$ holds. Now define the function $f(y,z)= x^{(y^z)}- y^{(z^x)}$. On one hand, $f(y,z)$ is identically zero, so all its first partials vanish.  On the other hand, we may compute them formally as $$f_y=\frac{x^{(y^z)}zy^z\ln{x} -y^{(z^x)}z^x}{y}\quad \mbox{and} \quad f_z=\ln{y}\left(x^{(y^z)}y^z\ln{x}-y^{(z^x)}xz^{x-1}\right)$$ Setting each of these to zero, and using the fact that $x^{(y^z)}=y^{(z^x)}$, we obtain $$zy^z\ln{x}=z^x\quad \mbox{and} \quad y^z\ln{x}=xz^{x-1}$$  From here it is fairly trivial to show that either $z=0$ or $x=1$, but each of these possibilities is ruled out by hypothesis.

Note that in the proof, I only used the asumption that $x^{(y^z)}= y^{(z^x)}$.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a careful look in a few hours.

Comment: I would say instead that $h(x,y,z) = x^{\left( y^z \right)} - y^{\left( z^x \right)}$ is $0$ along the line $x=y=z,$ meaning that its gradient, if defined, is orthogonal to the vector $(1,1,1)$ along that line. My suspicion is that the $0$ level surface of $h$ is a wiggly variant of a helicoid http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicoid wrapping around that line, so are the other two pairwise equality surfaces, and the three meet only along that line. perhaps offset by $120^\circ$ rotations.

Comment: Sounds plausable, Will.  I tried to think of the problem geometrically as well but soon relaized that the level surfaces were a bit too exotic for me to wrap my head around.  Recreational math should not make the brain hurt :-)

Comment: What's the domain of $f$?  In particular, why does it follow that it's identically $0$ from the assumption that you have a single $(x,y,z)$ off of the line $x=y=z$ for which $f(y,z)= 0$?

Comment: @Jason, You're right, I cannot make that assumption.  My "proof" is not a proof.  Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1):

It is an interesting problem.  I think that it gave you your cold.  I hope by now you are fully recovered.

I believe it never happens.

First, we can establish the result over the integers.  Supposing this double equality *ever* occurs, consider a minimal example.  Then any prime divisor $p$ of $x$ must divide both $y$ and $z$.  It means that $p^{(p^p)}$ divides each of $x^{(y^z)}$, $y^{(z^x)}$,  and $z^{(x^y)}$.  Division of all terms by $p^{(p^p)}$ now gives a smaller example, so a contradiction.

Moving to the rational numbers is now easy ... just a matter of clearing out the denominators and repeating the same basic argument.

To get the result over the reals is a bit more subtle, and I haven't worked it out entirely yet.  I'm thinking that a necessary first step is to realize each of $x$, $y$ and $z$ as the limit of a sequence of rational numbers.  You can try this yourself, as I'll be preoccupied for the next three days.

Best of luck with this interesting problem.  I will return to it when I get back to my home base.

Comment: Does dividing through by $p^{p^p}$ work? In particular, it isn't the case that $x^{y^z}/p^{p^p}=x/p^{y/p^{z/p}}$.

Comment: It might be easier to look at if you take logs twice, and you get $z\ln y+\ln\ln x = x\ln z+\ln\ln y = y\ln x+\ln\ln z$

Comment: To first order, if $x=p+a,y=p+b,z=p+c$, and $a,b,c$ are small compared to $p$, I think you need $c\ln p+b+a/(p\ln p)$ to equal its cyclic permutations.  Form a 3x3 matrix, multiply its inverse by the vector $(1,1,1)$

Comment: hm, you get a multiple of $(1,1,1)$.  Unless the determinant is zero.  Can you solve $(\ln p)^3+1+1/(p\ln p)^3 = 3/p$?

Comment: Doc, I hope this works out. I got nowhere.

Comment: Let $d=(\ln p)^3$.  If $p>1$, the left-hand side is at least $1+2p^{-3/2}$, and it isn't hard to show that is more than $3/p$ if $p>1$.  And if $\ln p<0$ then the left-hand side is less than 1, and the right-hand side is more than 3.  So I don't think you get any solutions near $x=y=z$.

Comment: My intuition is that it is extremely unlikely that *algebra* will prove useful in what is largely an *analytical* question.  Kudos on establishing the result on the rationals, though.