# Why does $\mathbb{Z}$ denote the set of integers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

The set of Natural Numbers is denoted by $\mathbb N$ (For Natural)

The set of Rationals are denoted by $\mathbb Q$ (for quotient)

The set of Complex numbers are denoted by $\mathbb C$ (for complex)

The set of Real numbers are denoted by $\mathbb R$ (for Real)

Why is the set of integers denoted by $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Zahl(en) = number(s) , in german.

Comment: Was the title inspired by this question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493739/this-is-stupid-but-i-have-a-bad-cold-with-cough/506001#comment1085972_506001 EDIT: The title was changed to something more reasonable.

Comment: I guess it is because the Germans happen to inhabit Earth (and Germany in particular for the most of them, but notational conventions often, and fortunately, do transgress national boundaries).

Comment: On Earth, in particular on Germany

Comment: A stupid memory aid is IntegerZ.

Comment: I remember it, but i just wanted to know why

Comment: Huh, I thought $\Bbb N$ was for "numbers".

Comment: @MJD: And I thought that $\Bbb C$ is for cookie, that was good enough for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I typed "*Integers*" into Google. The first hit was Wikipedia.

In the second paragraph it says "*The set of all integers is often denoted by a boldface Z... which stands for Zahlen (German for numbers).*"

Comment: And you made this an =answer= instead of a comment?

Comment: @ndroock1 Does it not *answer* the question?!

Comment: My point being: 9 upvotes ( sofar ) for a Wikipedia lookup, that's worse than plagiarism.

Comment: @ndroock1 You obviously don't understand the way this site works. It isn't a "show how clever you are by posting original research" site. It's a site where we try to answer questions. If a reliable source can be provided then so much the better. Upvotes are given for "useful" answers. Obviously nine people feel that answering the question and supplying a reference is useful. Don't you?

Comment: @ndroock1 I suggest that you try not to take the upvotes so seriously.  Nine upvotes and $3.50 will buy you a latte at Starbucks.

Comment: @MJD I couldn't agree more. In the past, I've spent 30 minutes typing a thoughtful and detailed response to a difficult and technical question and not received a single upvote for my troubles. The easier the question topic, the more traffic it gets and the more upvotes answers get.

Comment: Math.StackExchange: the show where everything is made up and the points don't matter!

Comment: @MJD That made me "LOL" :o)